# How do you get sticky posts to work with categories?

Tags: categories, sticky-post

How do you get sticky posts to work with categories?

I have tried:

```
$query->set( 'ignore_sticky_posts', 0 );
```

but this just results in an out of memory error.

I have tried restricting posts on the blog page by category, but sticky posts are shown regardless of which category they are in.

Why is this basic functionality so hard to achieve?
Is the only option to write two separate custom queries?

Comment: What do you mean by "with categories"? What exactly are you trying to solve?

Comment: If you go to a category page the default behaviour is to simply ignore sticky posts and treat them as a normal post, i.e. not at the top of the page